# Creating utility for label with Icon

Tags: ios, swift, icons, label

I wanted a UILabel with icon.

So i created a utility which will create label, icon and deal with constraints for spacing between them etc.

Now when i use this component in my client code, i again need to create a UILabel in storyboard.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var stateLabel: iconLabel! 
    ...
    stateLabel.style = withIcon
```

and

utility has prototype code:

```
struct style {

    static let withIcon = style(
    iconName = x.png,
    textColor: white
}

class iconLabel {
    createLabel() {
         label = UILabel()
          addSubview(label)
         //deal with constraints
    }
    createIcon() {
         icon = UIImageView
          addSubview(icon)
         //deal with constraints
    }
}
```

So problem is:
1)I have to have label in my client + in my utility. How to avoid this.
2)If i delete label from my client file, then that label has constraints with other labels in storyboard and i dont understand if i remove it, how can i use my utility. 
3)If i dont recreate label in utility, then how can i set constraints between label and icon.
4) If i dont create utility, then every client has to have UIImageView for icon and code for constraints betweein icon and label. So i wanted to create a utility.

Any hints ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried creating a custom uiview with a .xib-file?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question?  What do you mean by "utility"?   Are you talking about the need to have the same source file in two different apps?  You can create a framework for your label and include that framework in the two apps

Comment: @donmarkusi , do you  mean that .xib file will have my icon and label ? can you give more details ?

Comment: @Paulw11 utility means resusable component. i have just 1 app.

Comment: Ok, so either simply include this components code directly in your app, or if you think you want to be able to use it in other apps in the future package it as a framework or Cocoapod

Comment: Also, is your source code in your question what you actually have?  Your new label should be a UIView subclass, so the class that uses it sees a single object with your 'label' dealing with the text and icon internally

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this basic tutorial by apple for creating custom views:
[Custom controls](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson5.html)